# how to store the metadata of a filehieracrchy into sql table or csv file in adf?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a container in that there is a folder called loaded data in that I have subfolders also.
I need to store the metadata in the following  format  containername|foldername|foldername|filename
in a SQL table or file.

can anyone show the steps to achieve this.

Comment: Tell us your exact JDev version, please. Or is this an azure problem? Can you elaborate on the use case, please?

Comment: This is an azure problem. I need a pipeline in azure data factory which saves folder name,subfoldername and filenames in SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward approach will be to use an Azure function to get the all the metadata and then use Data Factory to store that result.

Comment: Just a Azure function that enumerates the container and inserts records into SQL server table is sufficient. Not necessary to use ADF.